# Search criteria based on dropdown - AngularJS Filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a question regarding `filter` to search on example name. This is easy to implement on ng-repeat.

The problem i have is actually that i want to filter based on either `name` or `account_name`(two different entity).

What i have tried is to make my input box filter on both `name` and `account_name` but with no success. What i did is this:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Search" ng-model="searchName.name">

<md-card flex="45" flex-sm="100" flex-md="100" flex-xs="100" ng-show="(account|filter:searchName).length > 0"
             ng-repeat="account in containers | groupBy: 'accountId' track by $index | filterBy: ['name', 'account_name']: searchName.name| filterBy: ['name', 'account_name']: searchName.account_name">

 <md-toolbar>
            <div class="md-toolbar-tools" ng-repeat="container in account | limitTo: 1">
                <h1 class="md-display-3"> <a href="{{container.tagManagerUrl}}">{{container.account_name}}</a></h1>
            </div>
        </md-toolbar>

(.... some code that is not important)

//table start
 <tr ng-repeat="container in account | filterBy: ['name', 'account_name']: searchName.name| filterBy: ['name', 'account_name']: searchName.account_name">
```

So i have:
1) Input field (search box)
2) `<md-card>` that is used on `ng-repeat`
3) `<md-toolbar>` assosiated with md-card but i must run ng-repeat here also
4) table with ng-repeat that shows entries.

This is the line ive tried:

```
filterBy: ['name', 'account_name']: searchName.name| filterBy: ['name', 'account_name']: searchName.account_name
```

But i cannot declare like in input field `ng-model="searchName.name && searchName.account_name"` this throws error

The **solution** i want to **try** is to have an Dropdown-menu where i can pick to filter by `name` or `account_name`
Looking like this:

[image]

If its possible to search by both account_name and name in just inputfield that would be great if not this is the way. Hope you can help me go forward and guide me of what i need and how i do it (dont need you to do all work).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to search by both account_name and name, you can pass an object to your filter.

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Search" ng-model="search.name">
<input type="text" placeholder="Search" ng-model="search.account_name">
<tr ng-repeat="container in account | filter:{name: search.name, account_name: search.account_name}>
</tr>
```

You can also use a custom filter for this,

js

```
  $scope.customFilter = function(row){   
    if($scope.Search == undefined || $scope.Search == "")
      return true;
    else if(row.name.indexOf($scope.Search) !== -1 || row. account_name.indexOf($scope.Search) !== -1)
      return true;
    else 
      return false;
  }
```

html

```
<tr ng-repeat="container in account | filter:customFilter>
</tr>
```

[**Demo**](https://plnkr.co/edit/SW0EonjjLsa7IcpN2Hjm?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks, but this is something i could do myself, but using just one input field is that possible?

Comment: for that you can use a custom filter, I will update my answer with code for custom filter

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help.